# Cron job is not working

Tags: php, cron

I have set up a cron job in cpanel in a standard way. I am trying to run a php file, when the email is delivered it gives me errors:

```
/home/shoes/public_html/webPages/products/time.php: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/shoes/public_html/webPages/products/time.php: line 1: `<?php include ('../../database/config.php'); ?>
```

How can I get this php script running perfectly? As when I load this using browser it gives out the actual result but not in cron.

Answer (score 4):

Did you put something like

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

in front of your PHP file? The error seems to say `sh` was used to run your PHP file, and it absolutely failed.

Comment: +1 Or, put `php scriptname` in crontab instead of just `scriptname`.